# Rotating an entire Tiled map ingame - LibGDX

Tags: java, libgdx, rotation, tiled

I've made a simple platformer game with a few levels and one of the mechanics is going to be rotating the entire level around 90 degrees at a time (animated) when something is triggered (just the level, not the player), though I could not find anything explaining how to do it so I have been assuming that it is just impossible to do with a map made with the Tiled software so I may need to look elsewhere. Is there any way that this could be accomplished? If you could explain it to me or even point me in the right direction I would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks for your time :D (Please let me know if I need to clarify further)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you use a `OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer` to render your `TileMap`, if so then you can use the `rotate` method on the `OrthographicCamera` to rotate before rendering.

For example

```
public class YourGameClass implements Screen {
    private final TiledMap map;
    private final OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer mapRenderer;

    private final OrthographicCamera camera;

    @Override
    public void render (float delta) {
        camera.rotate(1.0f * delta);  // Rotate a little on every update (you'll want to control this a bit more)
        camera.update();
        mapRenderer.setView(camera);

        mapRenderer.render();
    }
}
```

So basically you don't rotate the map, you rotate the camera that views the map.

Answer (score 1):

You have to do Two things

1.rotate Camera

2.change gravityDirection according to your camera rotation
code below for render method:

```
 //camera rotation
  gamecam.rotate(2f*dt);  

//update gravity direction

    gavityDirection.x-=0.5f*dt;
    gavityDirection.y+=0.5f*dt;

 //set required gravity

    world.setGravity(gavityDirection);
```